# What is the proper way to have a copy of redux state on a component prop

Tags: javascript, angular, redux

I have something like this:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.reduxServiceHandle = this.reduxService.subscribe(() =>
      this.reduxUpdates()
    );
  }

  reduxUpdates(): void {
    const newState: TransportationControlTowerState = this.reduxService.getState();
    // Check if feature groups object has changed
    if (!isEqual(this.groups, newState.groups)) {
      ...
      this.groups = newState.groups;
    }
  }
```

This is my reducer:

```
case TransportationControlTowerActions.ADD_GROUP:
  return newState = {
    ...state,
    groups: { ...state.groups, [payload.groupId]: payload.group }
  };
  break;
```

So, my question is: Do I need to clone deep the state before save it on this.groups prop? ***this.groups = newState.groups;***

I think that every time I change the redux state, I return a new state object so there won't be a problem with my local state(this.groups) pointing to the old state.

But I just want to make sure I am not following any anti pattern.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Official Redux docs says:

> State is read-only
>
> The only way to change the state is to emit an action, an object describing what happened.
>
> This ensures that neither the views nor the network callbacks will ever write directly to the state. Instead, they express an intent to transform the state.

You can view full list of core principles here https://redux.js.org/introduction/three-principles

Comment: I am not changing the state, I am dispatching an action and subscribing to the state updates, when something changes in the state I run a function to check if my local state is different than the new state if so I assign the new state to my local state